# Criar tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso criar, no banco de dados, a tabela abaixo, e inserir os valores apresentados.

A minha duvida é **qual seria a chave primaria nessa tabela ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**O ID_NF ?No exercicio pede para só criar essa tabela, mas ainda **não sei se devo criar outra tabela para ter sentido o id_nf, id_item e cod_prod.**

Poderiam me ajudar com isso ?

**Não tenho nenhum outro dado da tabela, só isso e que a partir dela serão feitas consultas como por exemplo Pesquisar os itens que foram vendidos sem desconto.**

Comment: Como existem diversos registros com o mesmo valor de `ID_NF` então este campo não poderia ser uma chave primária pois não identifica univocamente uma linha da tabela. Será que seu professor não quer que você aplique o processo de normalização?

Comment: Pode ser, mas olhando assim não sei como faria a normalização pois para mim ai já esta normalizado. Acho que seria coisa de ver chave primaria composta ou se preciso fazer as outras tabelas para usar foreign key nessa.

Comment: Você considera que, por exemplo, `valor_unit` não depende apenas do `cod_prod` mas pode variar com cada `id_nf` ou `id_item`, para concluir que a tabela apresentada está normalizada?

Comment: Eu estou começando em banco de dados, não sei muito.Por isso eu disse que não sei como fazer a normalização pois não sei como normalizar mais. Por mais que achasse qualquer coisa, não saberia normalizar essa tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Uma chave primária identifica univocamente uma linha da tabela. Em seu caso, ela seria composta de `ID_NF` e `ID_ITEM`. Em qualquer banco de dados (e o MySQL não é exceção) há funções para criar chaves primárias através de funções. Contudo, isto poderá trazer futuros problemas de desempenho e uma complexidade inicial indesejada. Assim, uma ideia básica seria criar uma coluna adicional, chamada, por exemplo `id` -- que seria gerado automaticamente pelo próprio gerenciador da base de dados.

Não há uma padronização muito rigida nestes casos, mas é comum usar-se como chave primária um nome no estilo `id_TABELA`. Por exemplo, se o nome da tabela for `notas`, sua chave primária seria `id_notas`.

Uma sugestão para a estrutura da tabela é

```
CREATE TABLE notas (
        notas_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        id_nf INT NOT NULL,
        id_item INT NOT NULL,
        cod_prod INT NOT NULL,
        valor_unit DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL,
        quantidade INT NOT NULL,
        desconto FLOAT
    );
```

Caso não queira criar uma chave adicional, a segunda forma da tabela poderia ser

```
CREATE TABLE notas (
        id_nf INT NOT NULL,
        id_item INT NOT NULL,
        cod_prod INT NOT NULL,
        valor_unit DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL,
        quantidade INT NOT NULL,
        desconto FLOAT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_nf, id_item)

    );
```

Um tutorial em português que explica grande parte dos itens (se não todos) dessas estruturas pode ser encontrado em [Definição de Dados - DDL](http://ehgomes.com.br/disciplinas/bdd/ddl.php)

Há alguns cuidados que não foram mencionados aqui: criação de um banco de dados que vai acomodar a tabela, e destruição da tabela caso exista. Mas deve haver o suficiente para um bom começo.